# Geopandas+linux=pyproj.exceptions.ProjError: x, y, z, and time must be same size

Tags: python, geopandas

I need to use the GeoDataFrame.to_crs("EPSG:4326",inplace=True) function to convert my vector layer to the WGS84 coordinate system.

My code was written on Windows, but the actual runtime environment is Linux.

On Windows, I need to set the environment variable 'PROJ_LIB'.

```
PROJ_LIB_PATH = r"D:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rasterio\proj_data"
def judege_platform():
    import platform
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = PROJ_LIB_PATH
    elif platform.system() == "Linux":
        pass
```

But I cannot find the location of 'PROJ_LIB' on Linux.

```
result_gdf.to_crs("EPSG:4326",inplace=True)
```

However, it will raise an error on Linux.

```
File "/root/anaconda3/envs/dzpro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 1364, in to_crs
geom = df.geometry.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg)
File "/root/anaconda3/envs/dzpro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geoseries.py", line 1124, in to_crs
self.values.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg), index=self.index, name=self.name
File "/root/anaconda3/envs/dzpro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/array.py", line 779, in to_crs
new_data = vectorized.transform(self.data, transformer.transform)
File "/root/anaconda3/envs/dzpro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/_vectorized.py", line 1114, in transform
new_coords_z = func(coords_z[:, 0], coords_z[:, 1], coords_z[:, 2])
File "/root/anaconda3/envs/dzpro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyproj/transformer.py", line 430, in transform
self._transformer._transform(
File "pyproj/_transformer.pyx", line 459, in pyproj._transformer._Transformer._transform
pyproj.exceptions.ProjError: x, y, z, and time must be same size
```

I have also set the 'PROJ_LIB' environment variable on the Linux platform.

```py
def judege_platform():
    import platform
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = PROJ_LIB_PATH
    elif platform.system() == "Linux":
        os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] ='/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasterio/proj_data'
```

However, this is not useful.

Comment: Assuming you've activated your `dzpro` conda env -  `os.environ["PROJ_LIB"]=os.path.join(os.environ["CONDA_PREFIX"], "share/proj")`

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading Shapely from 2.01 to 1.8.4 worked for me. Please refer to this link for further details https://cleanenergyfutures.insightworks.com/pages/9119.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/260150)